# PHP Curl Upload de Imagens

Tags: php, file-upload, libcurl

Estou tentando realizar o upload usando `cURL` em PHP em uma página externa. A princípio a linha de comando da página externa que captura as fotos é exatamente esse:

```
<!-- BEGIN FIELD IMAGES -->

<div class="form-col col-1">
    <label class="form-label label-with-obs">
        Adicionar imagens
    </label>
    <span class="form-label-obs">Até 6 imagens, extensões permitidas JPG, GIF e PNG somente.</span>
</div>
<div class="form-col col-2">
    <div class="line">
        <ul id="uploaded_images" class="list_ai-images"></ul>
        <div class="main-image-box hidden">
            <span class="main-box-label">Principal</span>
            <div class="image_box"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="wrapper_image_upload_button" class="wrapper-upload-button add-image">
            <div class="image">
                <span id="image_upload_button" class="btn-upload-image"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p id="err_extra_image" class="form-validation form-validation-success" style="display:none;">

</p>

    <p id="err_image" class="form-validation form-validation-success" style="display:none;">

</p>

    <p id="image_upload_status" class="mage_upload_alert form-validation form-validation-error"></p>
</div>
<!-- END FIELD IMAGES -->
```

Fazendo manualmente (acessando o site pelo meu navegador) e coletando o `array` enviado pelo post, eu tenho basicamente isso (testei enviando 1 foto qualquer do meu PC):

```
Array
(
    [image] => Array
        (
            [0] => 377529090726537.jpg
        )

    [thumbnail_digest] => Array
        (
            [0] => EMPTYDIGEST
        )

    [digest_present] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )

    [image_rotation] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )
)
```

**PS: Essa imagem `377529090726537.jpg` não é proveniente do meu PC. A imagem em questão tinha outro nome. Logo o formulário através do POST já tratou a imagem que foi feito upload. Provavelmente esse nome ai já é retorno do script.**

Ou seja, é feito upload ainda na página do formulário e quando é enviado para "tratamento" via Post, já é retornado o nome da imagem que foi hospedado no servidor.

A dúvida é: Diferente do envio que é feito via formulário ao qual a pessoa seleciona o caminho da imagem e envia pelo formulário que trata a imagem, esse sistema faz o upload da imagem ainda na primeira parte do formulário onde você preenche outros campos.

Nessa situação, como eu poderia obter êxito fazendo upload de uma imagem (ou melhor, 6 imagens) através da função `cURL` do php? Todo o resto do formulário eu consigo preencher, consigo enviar título, corpo de mensagem, seleciona input e combobox... mas esse do upload é novo para mim.

Afim de algo didático, suponhamos que o arquivo da imagem que eu queira fazer o upload se chama: `IMAGEM1.JPEG` e `IMAGEM2.JPEG`, elas estão disponíveis na mesma pasta que meu script curl, como proceder para fazer o upload para um sistema externo através do `cURL`?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o [`curl_file_create()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.curl-file-create.php), não é necessário fazer upload no servidor para depois enviar por `cURL`, você pode enviar direto apenas utilizando essa função.

```
$post[$key] = curl_file_create($file['tmp_name'], $file['type'], $file['name']);
```

Segue um exemplo de código que utilizo o upload via `cURL`:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ($url));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$post = array();

unset($data['file']);
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value)):
        if($value['error'] == 0):
            $post[$key] = curl_file_create($value['tmp_name'], $value['type'], $value['name']);
        endif;
    else:
        $post[$key] = $value;
    endif;       
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Poderia me explicar os atributos do comando? tmp_name, type e name?

Comment: é os valores que vem na variável `$_FILES`, como passo ele por função, acabo resgatando na variável `$data`

Comment: Considerando meu foreach com essa estrutura 'foreach ($xml->file[$i]->fotos->foto as $foto) {' como eu conseguiria usar esse curl_file_create?

Comment: no `foreach` a sua variável `$foto` contém os valores de `tmp_name`, `type` e `name`? Caso sim, basta colocar `$post[$key] = curl_file_create($foto['tmp_name'], $foto['type'], $foto['name']);`

Comment: Não... no meu foreach ele retorna a URL completa da imagem, exemplo: 'http://www.site.com/caminho/das/imagens/padrao/imagem12031931039.jpeg' Apenas isso. Por isso está difícil de entender sua ideia.

Comment: O meu código faz o upload direto para o `cURL` sem a necessidade de fazer upload no seu servidor, ele trabalha com o arquivo temporário e não com o arquivo real, para pegar direto de uma url seria diferente

Comment: Caramba, complicado! hahhaaha. E se eu usar regex para extrair o caminho da url e adicionar o caminho do servidor, como ficaria? Usando o exemplo do link acima, usar um regex para obter: `/usr/www/meusite.com/camunho/das/imagens/padrao/imagem12031931039.jpeg` e usar depois `curl_file_create($caminhoabsolutoimagem)'`sendo esse `$caminhoabsolutoimagem` resultado do regex de `$foto` ?

Comment: Eu não sou bom em regex, vou tentar criar o script para enviar o arquivo físico, qualquer coisa edito minha resposta

Comment: Acho que não precisa nem de regex, fiz dessa forma e consegui o caminho absoluto através da url recebida em `$foto` do meu foreach: `$foto = parse_url($foto);
 $caminhoabsoluto = $foto['path'];
 echo ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$caminhoabsoluto);`